Pushings files to Ec2 Instance using rsync
i have a directory on my local machine and want to push it to a ec2 instance.
Herre is the directory

I'm using rsync and have used the following commands
rsync /Users/abr032296/Desktop/Projects/ShinyAppHarold/Trended/PushToEc2/ ubuntu@10.104.35.171:/srv/shiny-server/DataScience/Senior/AbrCallAppTrending

rsync -azu /Users/abr032296/Desktop/Projects/ShinyAppHarold/Trended/PushToEc2/ ubuntu@10.104.35.171:/srv/shiny-server/DataScience/Senior/AbrCallAppTrending

Both return the following error
abr032296@LAP109053:/mnt/c/Users/abr032296$ rsync /Users/abr032296/Desktop/Projects/ShinyAppHarold/Trended/PushToEc2/ ubuntu@10.104.35.171:/srv/shiny-server/DataScience/Senior/AbrCallAppTrending
rsync: change_dir "/Users/abr032296/Desktop/Projects/ShinyAppHarold/Trended/PushToEc2" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]

abr032296@LAP109053:/mnt/c/Users/abr032296$ rsync -azu /Users/abr032296/Desktop/Projects/ShinyAppHarold/Trended/PushToEc2/ ubuntu@10.104.35.171:/srv/shiny-server/DataScience/Senior/AbrCallAppTrending
rsync: change_dir "/Users/abr032296/Desktop/Projects/ShinyAppHarold/Trended/PushToEc2" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

To test if the local directory exists, try cd /Users/abr032296/Desktop/Projects/ShinyAppHarold/Trended/PushToEc2/ and let us know what happened.

It really just looks like your local folder path is wrong, or maybe you don't have permissions to view it with that user.
Try changing into the PushToEc2 directory and doing a pwd and make sure it is exactly the same as the path you are using in that command, or maybe do do the rsync from one level up to make it easier.
rsync -a is likely enough too.
